# How to use string in IF condition in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have array
I have converted the array into string using implode function like below
i need the $str variable as condition in  if statement like below

```
[0]=>"1==1" 
[1]=>"1==1" 
[2]=>"2==1"
$str = "1==1 && 1==1 && 2==1";
if(1==1 && 1==1 && 2==1)
```

Comment: what is the problem???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it is not a good way to do such activity, you can use [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) for this:

```
<?php

$str = "1==1 && 1==1 && 2==1";

$condition = eval("return $str;");

if($condition) {
    echo "True";
} else {
    echo "False";
}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/573144) for False Situation

[Demo](https://eval.in/573146) for True Situation

Answer (score 0):

You can put the string into php eval() function.

```
$str = "1==1 && 1==1 && 2==1";
$question = eval("return $str;");

if ($question) {

} else {

}
```

I hope it will be usefull for you.

Comment: i can't convert the string into condition

Answer (score 0):

Try this code , i think you required this condition.

```
        $array[] = "1==1";
        $array[] = "1==1";
        $array[] = "2==1";

        $str = implode(" && ", $array);

        $condition = eval("return $str;");

        if($condition)
            return "true code";
        else
            return "false code";
```