# Evaluate string as condition PHP

Tags: php, eval

I have a custom validation rule module that essentially allows users to set up CSV validation. My problem is I get it to this array:

```
Array(
    [field_name] => 'is_int(324230435)',
    [some_other_field] => 'strlen("some str") > 25'
)
```

I did some research and came across the `eval()` function.

refs: [How to use string in IF condition in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37296199/how-to-use-string-in-if-condition-in-php)

However, I really don't want to use `eval()` due to the security issues (ref: [When is eval evil in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php))

Although it doesn't strictly say eval is evil, I still would prefer if there was an alternative method.

Am I being over-cautious about the usage of `eval()` - perhaps I should escape and use `eval()` or is there a better way?

Comment: Well, you want to execute a string as code. `eval` does that. This operation has the fundamental caveat that you want to *execute arbitrary strings as code*, which means you need to trust those strings. The alternative here would be to create your own parser and evaluator for your own mini-DSL, in which you can only form certain valid expression and don't open yourself up to *any arbitrary PHP code*.

Comment: Example: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language.html

Comment: What doesnt mix with eval is *user*, which you are going to do,. so its best not to use it. For 2 reasons, entering malicious code, and breaking the script by entering wrong syntax. You would be better off having allowed php functions in a drop down and then them selecting them adding the value and server-side executing them safely. So you would simply have a different array structure Array(
    [field_name] => [['func' => 'is_int', 'value' => 324230435]]
)

Comment: @deceze ah I see ... well I'm never a fan of trusting the user haha but I like the looks of that Symfony component - will give it a go ^.^ ty

Comment: You could deconstruct the string and then use [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, executing arbitrary strings as code has the caveat that you're *executing arbitrary code* whichever way you do it. There's no better alternative to `eval` that would let you execute PHP code without… executing PHP code.

The sane way to go here is to define a [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) which gives your users a way to write certain limited expressions *which are not PHP code*, which you will parse and evaluate with specific limited capabilities.

A good library which does that is [Symfony's ExpressionLanguage component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language.html). Beyond that you'd go into the domain of language parsers.

Answer (score 0):

Just going off of @deceze answer and suggestion to use Symfony's ExpressionLanguage Component.

I installed it to my project via Composer and thought for anyone stumbling across the post it might be helpful to see it working (and in relation to my question):

```
# build array for testing rows against rules
$test = [];

# foreach csv row
foreach ($csv as $keey => $row)
{
    # 10000s of rows, just for simplicity - break after 3
    if ($keey == 0) {continue;}
    if ($keey >= 3) {continue;}

    # get array keys for 
    $keys = array_keys($row);

    foreach ($keys as $key)
    {
        # if row key is in the $conditions array, add to $test array for testing
        if (in_array($key, array_map('strtolower', array_keys($conditions)))) {
            $conditionType = array_keys($conditions[$key]);
            $conditionType = $conditionType[0];

            if ($conditionType === 'condition_suffix') {
                $brokenCondition = explode(' ', $conditions[$key][$conditionType]);

                # build array to pass into ->evaluate()
                $test[$key]['evaluate'] = 'field '. $brokenCondition[0] .' required'; # expression to actually test
                $test[$key]['pass'] = [ # works like pdo, pass in the names and give them a value
                    'field' => strlen($row[$key]),
                    'required' => $brokenCondition[1]
                ];
            } else {
                $test[$key]['evaluate'] = 'field == required';
                $test[$key]['pass'] = [
                    'field' => is_numeric($row[$key]),
                    'required' => true
                ];
            }
        }
    }
}

echo '#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#';

# show test arr for reference
echo '<pre>';
print_r($test);
echo '</pre>';

# foreach test row, check against the condition
foreach ($test as $key => $item)
{
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($key. ': ' .$expressionLanguage->evaluate(
        $item['evaluate'],
        $item['pass']
    ));
    echo '</pre>';

    echo '+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+';
}
```

This now evaluates my custom created php query strings via the ExpressionLanguage Symfony component. Thanks @deceze

refs:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/syntax.html

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language.html