# If conditions inside a php variable

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

i already looked in the existing questions but nothing was close to my situation.

I would like to express a condition inside a variable. The problem is that if I use:

```
if($condition) {
```

it is true if $condition has a value, while i would like to make it true if the content of the variable is true:

```
$condition = “$a < 3”;
if($condition) {
```

The idea is that I store the conditions in the database, and I use them inside a while() according to the situation. I don’t know if I was clear, sorry if I wasn’t.

Hope you got the question, and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are looking for php eval https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

```
$test = 'return $a < 3;';
$test2 = 'return $a < 1;';

$a = 2;

if (eval($test)) {
    echo 'a < 3 ';
} else {
    echo 'a > 3 ';
}


if (eval($test2)) {
    echo 'a < 1 ';
} else {
    echo 'a > 1 ';
}
```

prints `a < 3 a > 1`

Be careful because `$test = "return $a < 3;";` would not compile as the var $a is not defined at that point so you should use single quotes so that its content is not interpreted.

Comment: `eval` can be dangerous. You might look at the [Symfony Expression Language](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/introduction.html) as an alternative.

Comment: @jeprubio thank you so much! eval() is the function i was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

$condition = ‘$_POST[‘abc’] == “xyz”’;
In this line you are using single inverted comma which will make it string
`$condition = $_POST[‘abc’] == “xyz";`
This will return boolean.

Comment: @TranslationsCloud oh, Sorry 
I think this link may help 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52315387/evaluate-string-as-condition-php